# Facebook API: Removing email permission - auth_revokeExtendedPermission

Tags: php, facebook

I want to remove the extended email permission if I only get the "@proxymail.facebook.com" email adress.

I use the new API version = 2.1.2

I tried this way, but that dont works:

```
$facebook->api('facebook.auth.revokeExtendedPermission',array(
    'perm' => 'email',
    'uid' => $uid
));
```

thx

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the proxymail address?

Comment: nothing wrong with it, it's better to have the real adress. I need to send notifications to users and I dont know if they get this like if I send to a proxymail adress ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to call this in a different way, because the `api` method on the FB PHP SDK is polymorphic.

Try this:

```
<?php

$facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'auth.revokeExtendedPermission',
'perm'   => 'email',
'uid'    => $uid
));
```